# Reshape mxn cell array to mxnxt 3D matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d, reshape, permute

I looked through past answers but I could find one that gave me a definitive answer for my case (weird as it seems simple).

I have a mxn cell array with each having a tx1 matrix and I would like to reshape this to a mxnxt 3D matrix. I saw a few example with permute and remat but did not get my answer there.

Thanks!

Comment: As a matter of semantics, there is no such thing as a "3D matrix."  Technically, it would be a "rank 3 array," or a "3D array."  Matrices are inherently 2D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need [`cell2mat`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) with a little of [`permute`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html):

```
c = repmat({(1:4).'},2,3); %'// example cell array
result = permute(cell2mat(permute(c,[3 1 2])), [2 3 1])
```